# Background service is not launching .net core with publishing on iis windows server

Tags: c#, iis, background-service, .net-7.0, windows-server-2022

i have a background service which work as a job on a specific time by using the library NCrontab
my project using .net 7
this is my background service

```
public class GenerateSiteMapXMLFileBackgroundService : BackgroundService, IHostedService
    {
        private CrontabSchedule _schedule;
        private DateTime _nextRun;
        public IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

        private string Schedule => "00 20 00 * * *"; //Runs every day at 00:20:00 (cron expression) {ss mm hh dd mm yy}
        public GenerateSiteMapXMLFileBackgroundService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            _schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse(Schedule, new CrontabSchedule.ParseOptions { IncludingSeconds = true });
            _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
            Services = services;
        }
        public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var scoped = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISiteMapeService>();
                do
                {
                    var now = DateTime.Now;
                    if (now > _nextRun)
                    {
                        await scoped.CreateSiteMapFile();
                        _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken); //5 seconds delay
                }
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
            }
        }
    }
```

and i've already registered it in startup.js

```
services.AddHostedService<GenerateSiteMapXMLFileBackgroundService>();
```

when i am testing it locally and set the time that i want, it works well and launch
but when i am publishing my project on iis server
it doesn't work
is there any configuration should i do on the iis server ?

i guess there are some configurations i have to do on the iis server
but i have no idea

Comment: You need to publish application and install on deploy machine which creates a setup.exe folder like any commercial software.  With Core one of the steps that is done is to install the runtime version of Core.

Comment: @jdweng
sorry I didn't get you

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: @jdweng
sorry I didn't get you
i am working on web api project and deploying it on iis windwos server

Comment: Note that you are using server local time when calling `DateTime.Now`, which may differ from your PC's local time. Maybe when you are expecting to see the cron result, the server has to wait a few more hours before executing it because it's in a different time zone.

Comment: A web project still need to be publish (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-aspnet-web-app?view=vs-2022&tabs=azure). Net/Core uses Windows dlls and for code to run on another machine to Windows dll on deploy machine has to match the dlls on the build machine.  A setup.exe updates Windows Dlls so an application will run on the deploy machine.  Core was developed so a c# application will run on Windows/Linux/MAC with little changes on the deploy machine.  A Core runtime library gets installed when you publish so that dlls do not need modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default IIS will shut down the application pool after a period of inactivity. Without configuring IIS, your background worker is not going to work as expected.

```
## IIS WebAdmin Module
Import-Module WebAdministration

$AppPoolInstance = Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\$AppPool

Write-Output "Set Site PreLoadEnabled to true"
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$Site -name applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled -value True

Write-Output "Set Recycling.periodicRestart.time  = 0"
$AppPoolInstance.Recycling.periodicRestart.time = [TimeSpan]::Parse("0");
$AppPoolInstance | Set-Item

Write-Output "Set App Pool start up mode to AlwaysRunning"
$AppPoolInstance.startMode = "alwaysrunning"

Write-Output "Disable App Pool Idle Timeout"
$AppPoolInstance.processModel.idleTimeout = [TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(0)
$AppPoolInstance | Set-Item

if ($appPoolStatus -ne "Started") {
    Write-Output "Starting App Pool"
    Start-WebAppPool $AppPool    
} else {
    Write-Output "Restarting App Pool"
    Restart-WebAppPool $AppPool
}
```

Or just edit the setting in IIS if you prefer the GUI.

[Credit](https://ankitvijay.net/2019/03/19/net-core-running-background-worker-on-iis/)